# how to test handler.postDelayed with mockito?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I am new to unit testing and I am stuck with testing following method:

```
    fun freeze(view: View) {
        view.isClickable = false
        handler.postDelayed({
             view.isClickable = true
        }, CLICK_TIMEOUT)
    }
```

Here is what I am already have:

```
    @Test
    fun freeze() {
        var view = mock<View>()
        viewUtil.freeze(view)
        assertFalse(view.isClickable)
    }
```

But now I need to test that view will be clickable after `CLICK_TIMEOUT`.

How can I implement this kind of test?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are able to mock `Handler` instance, you can do that:

```
Handler mockHandler = mock(Handler.class);
when(mockHandler.postDelayed(any(Runnable.class), anyLong())).thenAnswer(new Answer() {

    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        invocation.getArgumentAt(0, Runnable.class).run();
        return null;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble mocking final `postDelayed` method, but since it boils down to a non final `sendMessageAtTime`, I mocked that instead. Using a `spy` to avoid having to mock other `Handler` methods.

```
spyHandler = spy(new Handler(getMainLooper()));
doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Message message = invocation.getArgument(0);
            message.getCallback().run();
            return true;
        }
    }).when(spyHandler).sendMessageAtTime(any(Message.class), anyLong());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but in my case I should really run the actual `Runnable` with the actual `delay`, so base on @mrtowel answer I ended up with this code:

```
 Handler handler = mock(Handler.class);
 when(handler.postDelayed(any(Runnable.class), anyLong())).thenAnswer((Answer) invocation -> {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(invocation.getArgument(1));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ((Runnable) invocation.getArgument(0)).run();
        }).start();
        return null;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin just use the below

```
val handler: Handler = mock(Handler::class.java)
```

Runnable.postDelayed() ->

```
 `when`(handler.postDelayed(any(Runnable::class.java), anyLong())).thenAnswer {
            (it.arguments[0] as Runnable).run()
            true
        }
```

Runnable.post() ->

```
`when`(handler.post(any(Runnable::class.java))).thenAnswer {
            (it.arguments[0] as? Runnable)?.run()
            true
        }
```

imports

```
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers
import org.mockito.Mockito.*
```